# Is there any way to show me a link to the cities of a given province on the voivodships page?

Tags: easyadmin, symfony6

I have a ManyToOne relationship, many cities one province.
When adding a city, I have the option of choosing a province and everything is displayed correctly on the index page, each city has a link to the province.
Is there any way to show me a link to the cities of a given province on the voivodships page?

[image: City]
[image: Province]

```
class ProvinceCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Province::class;
    }

    /*public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->disable(Action::NEW, Action::EDIT, Action::DELETE);
    }*/

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('name'),
            AssociationField::new('cities')
        ];
    }
```

```
class CityCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return City::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('name'),
            AssociationField::new('province')
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved quite simply.
Here's the solution.

```php
class ProvinceCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Province::class;
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->disable(Action::NEW, Action::EDIT, Action::DELETE);
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('name')->setTemplatePath('admin/field/province/index/name.html.twig'),
            AssociationField::new('cities')
        ];
    }
}
```

name.html.twig

```php
    {# @var ea \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext #}
    {# @var field \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto #}
    {# @var entity \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto #}
    {% if ea.crud.currentAction == 'detail' %}
    <span title="{{ field.value }}">{{ field.formattedValue|raw|nl2br }} 
    </span>
    {% else %}
    {% set url = ea_url()
        .setController('App\\Controller\\Admin\\CityCrudController')
        .setAction('index')
        .set('filters[province][value]', entity.primaryKeyValue)
        .set('filters[province][comparison]', '=')
    %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ field.value }}</a>
    {% endif %}
```

[image: Province]
[image: City]
[image: Filters]